# Chrome Extension - Changing body height & width with transition gives buggy visual

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, transition

I am trying to increase/decrease the extension's width and height dimensions. I am trying to achieve that using body.

I have given `transition: 1s` to body.

Then with jQuery, using a checkbox result, I am changing body dimensions accordingly.

```
// Either:
$('body').css({ height: '600px', width:'800px'})

// Or:
$('body').css({ height: '400px', width:'400px'})
```

Everything should look good, however there is a glitch in the visual. [Here please check the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWHl6OLoWW6WlBESXN4Ukc4Qk0/view)

Am I doing something wrong?

---

So I am explaining the question in more detail:

- First create a popup script and place the html boilerplate (head, body) etc.
- Now give the body a static/hardcoded css attribute of width & height: `width: 400px; height: 400px`. Also give the body css `transition: 1s`
- Now, bind an event to  a toggle or a command, which will maximize/minimize the body's dimensions.

For that, I used jQuery:

```
 function changeBodySize() {
     var initialState = 0;  // maximize: 1, minimize: 0

     if (!initialState) {
        $('body').css({ height: '600px', width:'800px'})
        initialState = 1;
     } else {
        $('body').css({ height: '400px', width:'400px'})
        initialState = 0;
     }
  }
```

At this point, from the console, I trigger the function to maximize/minimize the body width & height with transition animation, and there is a visual bug, which is shown in Google Drive Video (which is a Streaming service, no need to download any file)

I hope this explanation is clear enough.

Comment: try and close the dev tools, sometimes it adds jank

Comment: I tried it too, definitely not that.

Comment: Looks like a bug, indeed. Report it on https://crbug.com

Comment: [Reported here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=748506&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: If you're going to include a screen video, please use a tool that will produce a GIF. You can then upload the GIF to StackOverflow's native servers and include it in your question. On Windows/OSX, this can readily be done with [LICECap](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=licecap). On Unix, there are other options. If it can be avoided, you should not expect us to download/access some random file in order to understand your question. Questions should be self-contained. As it is, your question will be considerably incomplete once that video is no longer accessible.

Comment: I added more details in the question. @Makyen, Google Drive video service does not require you to download any file, as far as I know. It streams the video directly, just like Youtube. Does it force you to download the video to watch it? I don't think so.

Comment: Was any progress made on this?